# Textinput - dúvida?

Tags: python-kivy

Gostaria de saber como capturar o texto dos `textinput`.

```
self.ids.grid.cols = 4
        for i in range(12):
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(TextInput(id = str(i+1), text = 'Teste'))
```

Por exemplo, gostaria de conseguir acessar cada `textinput`, e as propriedades deles.